# Отключить возможность выноса видео в отдельное окно

Tags: javascript, html, css, opera

В бразерах opera и yandex есть возможность выноса видео в отдельное  окно. Мне нужно на сайте отключить эту возможность. Как это сделать?

Кнопка для включения видео в отдельном окне появляется вот в таком вот блоке:

```
#shadow-root
```

Comment: Что бы данная кнопка не вылазила, я просто поверх окна видео выставляю прозрачный слой...

Comment: Выставил такой слой, кнопка все равно в опере вылазит. z-index ставил огроменный, все равно кнопка вылазит поверх всего.

Comment: покажи код.....

Comment: [URL=http://piccy.info/view3/11982785/37be179c9cde50d2b6fb3a1e23eb80c3/1200/][IMG]http://i.piccy.info/i9/04d90c121d742310e395e400ab8b29c2/1516525033/38186/1214761/code2_800.jpg[/IMG][/URL][URL=http://i.piccy.info/a3c/2018-01-21-08-57/i9-11982785/800x434-r][IMG]http://i.piccy.info/a3/2018-01-21-08-57/i9-11982785/800x434-r/i.gif[/IMG][/URL]

Comment: Для оперы нашел решение, 

body + div[is-visible] {display: none !important;}

А вот для яндекс браузера ничего в голову не приходит.

Comment: странно, opera, chrom & yandex  это один и тот же браузер... Движок хромовский у всех

Comment: @ДанилБилоголовский ставь `position: absolute` через `top`/`bottom`, `left`/`right` укажи местоположение элемента, а в `z-index` пиши это: `calc(9e999)`(Это максимально возможное число), может так сработает. Но на опере ведь только ~3%-5%(Ато и меньше) пользователей интернета, зачем она вообще?

Answer (score 1):

```
document.querySelectorAll('video').forEach(v => { v.setAttribute('pip', 'false'); }) //Yandex
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).